# Enable shortcuts in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextField and inside the frame, I have setup some shortcuts for some buttons and menu items. Once I start typing in the JTextField, when I press any of the shortcuts, it is not working as the current focus is on the text field. How can i remove this.

Below is my code so far. I have done it in netbeans.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    testTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!(Character.isDigit(c)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || c == '.'
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL))) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Only Numeric allowed");
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
    testButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);

    String keyCombination = "alt E";

    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCombination);
    testTextField.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyCombination);
    testTextField.getActionMap().put(keyCombination, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            testButton.doClick();
        }
    });
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    testButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    testTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

    jPanel1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    testButton.setText("Click");
    testButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            testButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(118, 18, 159, 96);
    jPanel1.add(testButton, gridBagConstraints);
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 146;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(119, 61, 0, 0);
    jPanel1.add(testTextField, gridBagConstraints);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void testButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.out.println("pressed");
}                                          
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JButton testButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField testTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   

}}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: How are you assigning shortcuts? Hopefully not with a KeyListener.

Comment: I am using mnemonics to set the shortcuts

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer: code also included

Answer (score 1):

So, three things jump out me...

### One...

You shouldn't be using `KeyListener`s on text components, there is just no guarantee that you will be notified before the `Document` of a key event or that the `Document` isn't in a state of change.  Also, this won't handle case where the user pastes text into the field...

Instead, you should be using a `DocumentFilter` to filter the content into the field...

- [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)
- [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

### Two...

There should be no need to add a key binding to the text field.  Not a bad idea, but if you have 10 fields and 10 short cuts, that's a lot of additional work to deal with...

In fact, a better solution would be to apply the key binding to the button itself...

### Three...

Mnemonics are used in combination with the text of the component to display a short cut to the user, this means that while the text of the button is `Click`, you will never be able to activate <kbd>Alt></kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Instead, you change the text to something that contains and `e`/`E` or the mnemonic to a character in the text, like <kbd>C</kbd>, it will work...

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
//        testTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
//            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
//                char c = e.getKeyChar();
//                if (!(Character.isDigit(c)
//                        || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
//                        || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || c == '.'
//                        || (c == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD)
//                        || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL))) {
//                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Only Numeric allowed");
//                    e.consume();
//                }
//            }
//        });
        testButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);

//        String keyCombination = "alt E";
//
//        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCombination);
//        testTextField.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyCombination);
//        testTextField.getActionMap().put(keyCombination, new AbstractAction() {
//            @Override
//            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                testButton.doClick();
//            }
//        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        testButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        testTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        jPanel1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        testButton.setText("Click");
        testButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                testButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(118, 18, 159, 96);
        jPanel1.add(testButton, gridBagConstraints);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 146;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(119, 61, 0, 0);
        jPanel1.add(testTextField, gridBagConstraints);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void testButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }
// Variables declaraÏtion - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton testButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField testTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: I have a button with me for which i have configured a shortcut. Once I am in the text field and press the shortcut, it wont work. So i need to overcome this problem. Could you please explain this setFocusAccelerator method in such a way so that it will solve my problem?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Here my concern is that the text field should only contain numeric characters and no alphabets are to be allowed. And while the focus is on the text field, i am unable to use a shortcut key without the KeyListener being invoked. I need a way to overcome this situation.

Comment: `DocumentFilter` for the `JTextField`, the examples link has a numeric filter.  You can apply a keybinding to the button if you need to or simply work within the mnemonics api requirements

Comment: I just posted an answer. Please verify once.

I am not able to upvote any of the answers as it requires 15 reputations.

Comment: @user2617306 Seriously, what's wrong with using a `DocumentFilter`, this is exactly what they are designed for.  A `Document` shouldn't be interacting with user interface as it can be constructed without one.  I would also be careful with using `setFocusCycleRoot`, as this could screw with other containers within the UI...

Comment: is it any way possible to contact you personally?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use shortcuts you need to use [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), here is how you can use `alt+E` combination on `textfield`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KLisDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel comp = new JPanel();

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

        String keyCombination = "alt E";

        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCombination);
        textField.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyCombination);
        textField.getActionMap().put(keyCombination, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText("ALT+E was pressed");
            }});

        comp.add(textField);
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In case I have already assigned Alt+E to another button, how can i invoke that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and below is the code. Please update in case of any better answers.

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
testButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);


    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        testButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        testTextField = new NumberField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        jPanel1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        testButton.setText("Click");
        testButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                testButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(118, 18, 159, 96);
        jPanel1.add(testButton, gridBagConstraints);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 146;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(119, 61, 0, 0);
        jPanel1.add(testTextField, gridBagConstraints);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void testButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }                                          


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton testButton;
    private NumberField testTextField;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}




public class NumberField extends JTextField {

    @Override
    protected Document createDefaultModel() {
        return new Numberdocument();
    }    
}


class Numberdocument extends PlainDocument {

    String numbers = "1234567890-";

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (!numbers.contains(str)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Only Numbers Allowed");
        } else {
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }

}
```